# The SharePoint can not find the model of the content type

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, document-template

I'm using SharePoint Online (2013), I created a document library with content type models. You never create a document, it will always use a template. 
I already have the models created, until yesterday everything worked normally.

But today when I did some tests, the models were not opened. I received the message that the template files were deleted or renamed. I checked the content types and files are there and open normally.

Anyone have any idea could have happened? Or better, any idea how to solve this?